# Can I somehow get the list of available error code constants for the NSErrorDomain: CloudPhotoLibraryErrorDomain?

Tags: xcode, nserror

Is there a way to get the list of code constants provided by apple for the `NSErrorDomain`: `CloudPhotoLibraryErrorDomain`. Specifically, I am looking for a constant for code **`81`**.

Any advice/suggestions are welcome!